# Issue adjusting iframe height when opened as popup using ModalPopupextender

Tags: asp.net, iframe, height, modalpopupextender

I am using a ModalPopupextender Ajax Control to open aspx page in a modal Popup. aspx page is opened in a iframe as shown in below code.The content which is loaded in iframe is dynamic hence I cannot give a fixed height to iframe. I want that I should be able to adjust the height as per the content every time popup is being opened. I have a function to resize the iframe height and I am using that successfully on my other pages where iframe gets populated in the window itself but not able to adjust the height when iframe is opened in a POPUP. I have already tried window onload, iframe onload events without any success.

```
     <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" BackgroundCssClass="transparentBG"
        runat="server" CancelControlID="ButtonCancel" OkControlID="ButtonDone" 
        TargetControlID="btnAddNew" PopupControlID="DivAddWindow" Drag="true"  >
     </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
     <div class="popup_Buttons" style="display: none">
      <input id="ButtonDone" value="Done" type="button" />
      <input id="ButtonCancel" value="Cancel" type="button" />
     </div>
     <div id="DivAddWindow" style="display: none;">

     <iframe id="IframeEdit" scrolling="no" src="MasterPage.aspx"  width="700px">
    </iframe>
   </div>
```

I would really appreciate if somebody can lead me the solution to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <iframe id="IframeEdit" onload="iframeLoaded()" scrolling="yes" src="MasterPage.aspx"  width="700px">
</iframe>
```

following javascript function would get height from the iframe content.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function iframeLoaded() {
    var iFrameID = document.getElementById('IframeEdit');

    if (iFrameID) {
        iFrameID.height = "";
        iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
}
</script>
```

I checked it in even ModalPopupextender, it works.

Comment: Thanks for the lead. Setting scrolling =yes indeed resolved the height issue but in Firefox, iframe shows Horizontal/Vertical scroll. May be I need to find a way to hide these through CSS.